# animate a UIView using CADisplayLink 'combined' with CAMediaTimingFunction. (to get a arbitrary curve)

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I am using a `CADisplayLink` to do a view animation that just interpolates a value and redraws the view itself.

e.g. I have a view `MyView` and it has a property `value`, whenever value is set I call `setNeedsDisplay` and the view knows what to draw.

to animate this I use `CADisplayLink` and I want the view to 'morph' between values. I do this by just interpolating the value from the animation's start and stop Value:

`- (CGFloat)interpolatedValue:(CGFloat)sourceValue withValue:(CGFloat)targetValue forProgress:(CGFloat)progress;`

now getting a linear progress is easy and getting a 'specific curve' (ok) but I want to be able to take advantage of `CAMediaTimingFunction` to do this (or some other preexisting logic - I don't want to reinvent the wheel again' :)

Comment: why use CADisplayLink? it's just a timer. And CAMediaTimingFunction is just store some key arg of curve. itself not do the curve. if all you want is a custom property getting full support of Core Animation, which just like a standard animatable property, you should inherit CALayer. see `Adding Custom Properties to a Layer` in Xcode doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this awesome gist [`RSTiming`](https://gist.github.com/raphaelschaad/6739676) which might be handy in your case. You can define timing functions either using standard CAMediaTimingFunction or even define custom ones using 2 control points to define a bezier curve.

If I got your setup, you may have something like this:

**ViewController**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AnimatedView.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AnimatedView *viewToAnimate;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateFrame)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)updateFrame {
    [self.viewToAnimate updateAnimation];
}

- (IBAction)updateAnimationTapped:(id)sender {
    self.viewToAnimate.value = arc4random_uniform(101) / 100.0;
    NSLog(@"Next animation value: %f", self.viewToAnimate.value);
}

@end
```

**AnimatedView**

```
#import "AnimatedView.h"
#import "RSTimingFunction.h"

@interface AnimatedView()
{
    CGFloat _lastValue;
    CGFloat _progressStep;
    CGFloat _currentProgress;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) RSTimingFunction *animationProgress;

@end

@implementation AnimatedView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        _progressStep = 0.01; // defines animation speed
        _currentProgress = 1.0;
        self.animationProgress = [RSTimingFunction timingFunctionWithName:kRSTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setValue:(CGFloat)value {
    if (_value != value)
    {
        _lastValue = _value;
        _value = value;
        _currentProgress = 0.0;
    }
}

- (void)updateAnimation
{
    if (_currentProgress > 1.0)
        return;

    _currentProgress += _progressStep;
    CGFloat currentAnimationValue = _lastValue + (_value - _lastValue) * [self.animationProgress valueForX:_currentProgress];

    self.alpha = currentAnimationValue; // as an example animate alpha
}

@end
```

As said you can even set 2 control points to create a timing function modelled on a cubic Bezier curve.

```
self.animationProgress = [RSTimingFunction timingFunctionWithControlPoint1:CGPointMake(0.6, 0.6) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(0.1, 0.8)];
```

Which will produce the following timing animation (produced using [CAMediaTimingFunction playground](http://netcetera.org/camtf-playground.html))

[image]