# Swift: Animate object along animating path

Tags: swift, animation, caanimation

I would like to animate little red dot rotating around circle that is expanding in a pulse manner (go from small to big, then start back from small). It seems that little dot keeps rotating around original shape and does not take into account that circle it's expanding... I have this in code:

```
// MARK: - Properties

  private lazy var containerView = UIView()

  let littleCircleRadius: CGFloat = 10

  private lazy var littleRedDot: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    let littleDotSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: containerView.bounds.center.x - littleDotSize.width / 2,
                         y: containerView.bounds.center.y - littleCircleRadius - littleDotSize.width/2 ,
                         width: littleDotSize.width,
                         height: littleDotSize.height)
    return layer
  }()

 private lazy var littleCircleLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.lineWidth = 1.5
    layer.lineCap = .round
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    return layer
  }()

// MARK: - Setup
 func setup() {
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 200, width: 300, height: 300)
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

    littleCircleLayer.path = makeArcPath(arcCenter: containerView.bounds.center, radius: 10)
    containerView.layer.addSublayer(littleCircleLayer)
    containerView.layer.addSublayer(littleRedDot)
}

// MARK: - Animations
func animate() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.5)
    animateLittleRedDotRotation()
    animateCircleExpanding()
    CATransaction.commit()
}

func animateLittleRedDotRotation() {
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    anim.duration = 1.5
    anim.rotationMode = .rotateAuto
    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    anim.path = littleCircleLayer.path
    littleRedDot.add(anim, forKey: "rotate")
}

func animateCircleExpanding() {
    let maxCircle = makeArcPath(arcCenter: containerView.bounds.center, radius: 100)
    let circleExpandingAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    circleExpandingAnim.fromValue = littleCircleLayer.path
    circleExpandingAnim.toValue = maxCircle
    circleExpandingAnim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    circleExpandingAnim.duration = 1.5
    littleCircleLayer.add(circleExpandingAnim, forKey: "pulseCircuitAnimation")
}
```

This creates following effect:

[image]

However I would like to achieve for little dot to be rotating along the expanding circle path (as it animates from small circle to bigger circle), not the original small circle path. Any ideas ?

Comment: update frame of little  dot ....

Comment: if you can share full class ... i will be able to recreate and check

Comment: This is the whole content of my playground https://gist.github.com/ZaweSK/7c9c06307593c64e2c22cde78e9aa6cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CoreAnimation to animate the position of the red dot based upon the path assumes that the path isn't changing. You could, theoretically, define a spiral path that mirrors the expanding circle. Personally, I'd just use `CADisplayLink`, a special timer designed optimally for screen refreshes, and retire the CoreAnimation calls entirely. E.g.

```
func startDisplayLink() {
    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
    displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
}

@objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    let percent = CGFloat(displayLink.timestamp).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: duration) / duration
    let radius = ...
    let center = containerView.bounds.center
    circleLayer.path = makeArcPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius)
    let angle = percent * .pi * 2
    let dotCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + cos(angle) * radius, y: center.y + sin(angle) * radius)
    redDot.path = makeArcPath(arcCenter: dotCenter, radius: 5)
}
```

That yields:

[image]

---

The full example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let radiusRange: ClosedRange<CGFloat> = 10...100
    private let duration: CGFloat = 1.5

    private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    private lazy var redDot: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return layer
    }()

    private lazy var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.lineWidth = 1.5
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return layer
    }()

    private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setup()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startDisplayLink()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        stopDisplayLink()
    }
}

// MARK: Private utility methods

private extension ViewController {
    func setup() {
        addContainer()

        containerView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        containerView.layer.addSublayer(redDot)
    }

    func addContainer() {
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func makeArcPath(arcCenter: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }
}

// MARK: - DisplayLink related methods

private extension ViewController {
    func startDisplayLink() {
        stopDisplayLink()  // stop existing display link, if any

        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        self.displayLink = displayLink
    }

    func stopDisplayLink() {
        displayLink?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        let percent = CGFloat(displayLink.timestamp).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: duration) / duration
        let radius = radiusRange.percent(percent)
        let center = containerView.bounds.center
        circleLayer.path = makeArcPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius)
        let angle = percent * .pi * 2
        let dotCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + cos(angle) * radius, y: center.y + sin(angle) * radius)
        redDot.path = makeArcPath(arcCenter: dotCenter, radius: 5)
    }
}

// MARK: - CGRect extension

extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY) }
}

// MARK: - ClosedRange extension

extension ClosedRange where Bound: FloatingPoint {
    func percent(_ percent: Bound) -> Bound {
        (upperBound - lowerBound) * percent + lowerBound
    }
}
```

Comment: this is really nice approach Rob. Thank you 

Comment: I have one more question. With this approach is it also possible to use some sort of timing function so that animation would not be drawn with linear timing ? I mean, could I get the same same result but with lets say .easeIn. timing ? (what I really need is custom timing function defined by Beziere  curve (0,0, 0.25, 1))

Comment: I believe you have to write your own easing timing functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30454591/1271826 for bezier examples. Or you can do your own, e.g., for trigonometric curve that approximates ease in and ease out, I’ve use _1 - cos(πt)_ where _t_ is in [0,1].